# What is a good way to get ENUM values from a ENUM representing some Weekdays

Tags: java

I have an `ENUM` with only 3 constant. Based on flag, named `weekend`, ENUM.values() should return either 3 or 2 constants.

```
public enum Weekday { 
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY;
}

public Weekday[] getDays() {
    boolean weekend = true;
    if (weekend){
        return Weekday.values() // this will reurn SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY
    } else { // when weekend is false
         return Weekday.values() // it should return on MONDAY, TUESDAY
      }
}
```

Please suggest, what is the a reasonable good approach to achieve this. I am able to achieve it with the below code. Unfortunately, the PR reviewer does not seem to be happy this that. Could you suggest a better approach?

My solution.

```
 EnumMap<Weekday, Integer> days= new EnumMap<>(Weekday.class);
    days.put(Weekday.MONDAY, 1);
    days.put(Weekday.TUESDAY, 2);

    return days.keySet().toArray(new Weekday[0]); // this returns MONDAY and TUESDAY.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
 public enum Weekday {
        SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY;
    }

    public Weekday[] getDays() {
        boolean weekend = callFromSomeAPI();
        return weekend ? Weekday.values() : new Weekday[] {Weekday.MONDAY, Weekday.TUESDAY};
    }
```

Of course, in a more typical use of the Enum `Weekday` would be to represent **all the 7 days of the week**, and using a variable (*e.g.,* `weekend` or `weekdays`) to differentiate from week days and weekend days. Something like:

```
enum Weekday {
    MONDAY(false),
    TUESDAY(false),
    WEDNESDAY(false),
    THURSDAY(false),
    FRIDAY(false),
    SATURDAY(true),
    SUNDAY(true);

    private final boolean weekend;

    Weekday(boolean weekend) {
        this.weekend = weekend;
    }

    public static Weekday[] getDays(boolean weekend) {
        return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(i -> i.weekend == weekend).toArray(Weekday[]::new);
    }
}
```

Comment: @dreamcrash your code looks good to me. I would try this and will see if it makes the review happy :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The [Answer by dreamcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65010056/642706) is correct. I’ll add a few notes.

## `DayOfWeek`

Java provides your enum in the *java.time* package: [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).

No need to define your own Enum here for your purpose.

## Non-modifiable `List`

Instead of an array, you can return a [non-modifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) `List` using convenient methods [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)).

```
public List< DayOfWeek > getDays() {
    boolean weekend = callFromSomeAPI();
    return weekend ? List.of( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY , DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) : List.of( Weekday.MONDAY, Weekday.TUESDAY );
}
```

Being non-modifiable, you can keep a single copy of each list as a `static` constant for repeated use.

```
static final List< DayOfWeek > WEEKEND = List.of( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY , DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) ;
static final List< DayOfWeek > FIRST_WEEKDAYS = List.of( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) ;
```

…and…

```
public List< DayOfWeek > getDays() {
    boolean weekend = callFromSomeAPI();
    return weekend ? WEEKEND : FIRST_WEEKDAYS ;
}
```

With proper naming of such constants, your code gets shorter and more readable while your intentions become more obvious.

If the calling programmer really wants an array, they can call [`List::toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)).

```
… whatever.getDays().toArray( new DayOfWeek[0] ) …
```

## `EnumSet`

The class [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) provides similar-looking `of` methods but:

- are *modifiable*.
- are *highly optimized* for holding enum objects, being fast to
  execute while taking very little memory.

The `EnumSet` iterator returns the enum in order of their enum definition. In `DayOfWeek` that order is MONDAY to SUNDAY per [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. So this approach may not work for you if you were depending on Sunday being first (if so, stick to using a `List`).

```
Set< DayOfWeek > getDays( String flag )  
{
    if ( flag.equalsIgnoreCase( "weekend" ) ) // Better to use an enum as your flag rather than error-prone strings. 
    {
        return EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY , DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) ) ;  // Be aware: This EnumSet will iterate in Monday-Tuesday-Sunday order, the order of their definition in the Enum. 
    } else 
    {
        return EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) ) ;
    }
}
```